# Test current hour in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, date

How to test if current hour is equal to a given hour in shell?
The hour should be in 24-hour format.

How to realize this?

```
While true:
    do
    current_hour = ...
    if current_hour == 21:
        python aaa.py
    done
```

Comment: Is it possible to schedule the python program using `at`? [man at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at)

Comment: If you mean you want to run once at 21:00, make a `crontab` entry. Or do you mean, as written, you want to run your Python as many times as possible between 21:00-21:59 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  while true; do
      hour=$(date +%H)
      if [ $hour == 21 ] ; then 
          python aaa.py
      fi
      # now sleep until next hour
      sleep $(((60 - $(date +%M))*60))
  done
```